# jqGrid Drag and Drop Between Groups in the Same Grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

I'm using jqGrid, and looking for a way to drag and drop rows between groupings in the same table. Dropping a row from one group to the other group will change the value in the row that the table is currently grouped by.

For example, if I have a table of tasks grouped by due date, dragging a task to a different due-date group would update that row's due date to the value of the group the row is dropped on.

Is this even possible with jqGrid?!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

JQGrid also basically Table. So get the jqgrid table id initialize drag-and- drop-able table  and then use..

Default there is no way to do...

Thanks